# Calling PageMethods from pageLoad

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

i wanted to call a code behind from javascript during pageLoad event.
However,i am receving PageMethods not define error.

using he same code changing from pageLoad to a function.I didnt received that error.
so my guessingw as that we can't call a serside function during page load?

```
  <script type='text/javascript'>
     function callserver() {
         PageMethods.fromcodebehind();
'call from button works fine
     }
</script>
 <script type='text/javascript'>
     function pageLoad() {
         PageMethods.fromcodebehind();
        ' calling from page load does not works
     }
</script>
```

Comment: Well, just calling a method PageLoad() in JavaScript doesn't mean it's going to be called automatically.  How are you calling the pageLoad() JavaScript method in your second example?

Comment: second example is calling from pageload and first example is calling from a button. calling from button works fine while calling from page load does not work. after some search, i think pageMethods does not work on pageLoad event.

Comment: Put an alert() statement in your pageLoad() JavaScript method.  It may not even be executing.